# Decoding HMC5883L 3-axis magnetometer output

Tags: sensors, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I have working code for the HMC5883L 3-axis magnetometer, but don't understand how to convert the output into usable data. Running this in MicroPython on a Raspberry Pi Pico. I reviewed the post using i2clibraries HMC5883L library for Raspberry Pi Pico, but Thonny doesn't find any such library in PyPi for Micropython.

IC documentation states:

> To clock out the new data, send:
> 0x3D, and clock out DXRA, DXRB, DZRA, DZRB, DYRA, and DYRB

and:

> The  format  of  the  data  bytes  (payload)  shall  be  case  sensitive  ASCII  characters  or binary data to the HMC5883L slave, and binary data returned. Negative binary values will be in two’s complement form. The default (factory) HMC5883L 8 -bit slave address is 0x3C for write operations, or 0x3D for read operations.

Regardless of gain range, output values are supposed to only be: 0xF800–0x07FF (-2048–2047 ). This means LSB values are used as is, but there is manipulation needed for the MSB since full number is 10-bit with 11th bit being the sign. Output for 12th bit and up were set arbitrarily to 0 or 1 (depending on last change of sign), thus initial data looked like gibberish converted to numbers. Several code examples of the HMC5883L *incorrectly* use the unnecessary bits resulting in output looking like a step function.

This correctly gets the sign and only the valid 10-bit number:

```
addr = 0x1e
cmd_meas = b'\0x3D\0x06'

while 1:
    i2c0.writeto(addr, cmd_meas)
    time.sleep_ms(100)

    # Reads data in binary format
    data = i2c0.readfrom(addr,6)

    #print(f"{data[0]:0>8b}  {data[1]:0>8b}")

    # Data is a 10 bit number with the 11'th bit as the sign
    # MSB has the sign bit in position 2 (counting from zero)
    # 11111011
    #      ^ sign bit here
    # Need to ignore everything to the left of the sign in MSB
    # Use bitwise shifts to mask sign bit
    # Then set all MSB bits 2 and up to zero
    # Bit shift MSB to the left, add to LSB
    # Multiply by sign to get actual values
    # Two's compliment sign convention: 0 is positive, 1 is negative

    filt = range(2,8)

    xmsb = data[0]
    zmsb = data[2]
    ymsb = data[4]

    xsign = (xmsb & (1 << filt[0])) >> filt[0]
    ysign = (ymsb & (1 << filt[0])) >> filt[0]
    zsign = (zmsb & (1 << filt[0])) >> filt[0]

    xsign = -1 if xsign == 1 else 1
    ysign = -1 if ysign == 1 else 1
    zsign = -1 if zsign == 1 else 1

    for i in filt:
        xmsb &=~ (1 << i)
        ymsb &=~ (1 << i)
        zmsb &=~ (1 << i)

    xval = xsign*(xmsb << 8 | data[1])
    yval = ysign*(ymsb << 8 | data[5])
    zval = zsign*(zmsb << 8 | data[3])

    print(f'x: {xval} y: {yval} z: {zval}')
```

I confirmed output values are within expected range of -2048 to + 2047. I've seen arduino.h code for this sensor which state tangential xy magnetic component is used to calculate compass heading. But I have yet to find the actual code to figure out the math.

How do I manipulate the output to get relative position in X-degrees, Z-degrees, Y-degrees? Is there a code example to convert output range to relative compass heading, or pitch/roll?